# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required in Python3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, element, sequence

Something went wrong with python3.10, no warning or any notice in the Pycharm validation.
It just recommended the space by following the PEP 8: E231 missing white space after ':'

```
class Margin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__margin = {}

    def setMargin(self, value: dict= None) -> None:
        self.__margin.update(value or {'all': '', 'android': {}, 'ios': {}})
```

Calling the method without a parameter

```
obj = Margin()
obj.setMargin()
```

Then everything was fine with adding space, but on the run time, it showed me the error.

```
 File "/var/www/avb/n.py", line 1195, in setMargin
    self.__margin.update(value or {'all': '', 'android': {}, 'ios': {}})
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: I guarantee that's not the issue. What's `value`? Can you edit the question to give a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry, it missed a statement. Please kindly check again.

Comment: I'm afraid this is still not a [mcve]. And the main problem is in fact in the code which is missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error generally,

when you try to update a dictionary like this:

```
d = {}

d.update([(100,)])
```

#or

```
d.update([[1]])
```

#output

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

You also get this error when you have dictionary inside a string like this:

```
d = '{"a":1,"b":2}'
```

then you try to convert it into a dictionary by:

```
dict(d)
```

#output

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

You have to check how you have defined your class and how the object `obj` is created.